# display html table form database in shortcode - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I have a table in the database that contains HTML().
I am retrieving it correctly and I try to generate a shortcode with this data but it doesn't work properly. I made a lot of research on google but not able find anything... Here is my code

```
public static function fln_table_shortcode() {

            global $wpdb;
            //$table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'generated_tables';

            $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_generated_tables WHERE table_id = 7',OBJECT );

            foreach ($results as $data) {

                foreach ($data as $key=>$value){
                    if($key =="html_table"){
                         $content = $value;

                    }
                }


                }



            }


        $striped = stripslashes($content);
            return $striped";// this var contains html code <table>
            //echo $striped." this is the table";
        }

    public static function fln_register_shortcodes() {
        add_shortcode( 'table_shortcode', array( 'FinancialShortcodes', 'fln_table_shortcode' ) );
    }
```

Any Ideas? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jesus, why do you store HTML in a database? You can easily iterate through your data with Template engines or other engines. If you have access to your server where wordpress is running, just install an template engine and it would be much structured and easier

Comment: There is reason for that because a css functionality will be developed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, add this to your functions.php

```
function fln_table_shortcode() {
        global $wpdb;
        //$table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'generated_tables';

        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_generated_tables WHERE table_id = 7',OBJECT );
        $content = "";
        foreach ($results as $data) {
            foreach ($data as $key=>$value){
                if($key =="html_table"){
                     $content .= stripslashes(html_entity_decode($value));
                }
            }
        }
        return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'table_shortcode','fln_table_shortcode');
```

Hope this will helps you.